# TableLayoutPanel Rows AutoHeight Around Text?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Hi I was wondering how I can get my TableLayoutPanels to resize (height) automatically depending on how much text is inside of them.  for instance, if I have 5 lines of text, I'd like my row to be 5 lines high, if I have 1 line of text, I'd like my row to be 1 line high.

This is the way tables work natively in HTML, and that's basically what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the problem? Make the cell in TableLayoutPanels AutoSize, and columns left and right to the cell AutoSize.
[image]
[image]

And the result is:

[image]